# THC/THC.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, pytorch, compiler-errors, nvidia, libtorch

I am trying to compile this with cuda support: https://github.com/CharlesShang/DCNv2 for a Project. But everytime I try it gives me this error message:

```
/THC.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <THC/THC.h>
```

I am using:

- Arch Linux with kernel version 6.1.4
- GTX 1080
- python 3.6
- pytorch 1.2.0
- torchvision 0.4.0
- cudatoolkit 10.0
- gcc 7.5

I thought it might be incompatible cuda and gcc versions, but I tried multiple combinations and none of them worked. At the moment I am using cuda 10.0 with gcc version 7.5 as it should be compatible.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: THC is a core component of libtorch. Your problem isn't related to CUDA